# How does chrome empty cache?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

Chrome has a feature where if you double click the refresh button, you can empty cache and hard reload. How does chrome empty the cache? I'm well aware that, on a Mac, if you it command+shift+delete, you can clear cookies and cache. However, I don't want to go this route, and I only want to clear the cache. The reason why I want to know how it's being done is because I'd like to attach a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Doesn't a shorcut already exist?  `Shift+Command+R`

Comment: All you are doing by hitting the refresh twice, is using a [workaround](Shift-reload support), that doesn't always work

Comment: The above comment was suppose to point to a Chromimum bug where that was suggested, the bug report, in in the duplicate though.